# How to redirect the user to login page, after the refresh token has expired

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using axios, reactjs, react-router-dom and redux.
I am trying to send the user to the login page, when the refresh token expires, but I cannot use react-router-dom in an axios file, so I do not know how to re-direct the user.
To get worse, when the token expires, the app enters a infinite loop, till the browser crashes.
Any pointers or solutions?

```
// App.jsx
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Topics from "./components/Topics";
import Root from "./components/Root";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard";
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { login, logout } from "./redux/actions/authActions";
import React from "react";
import EmployeeList from "./components/EmployeeList";

function App() {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // Function to handle user login
  const handleLogin = () => {
    dispatch(login());
  };

  // Function to handle user logout
  const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  };

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Login onLogin={handleLogin} />} />
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <Route path="/" element={<Root onLogout={handleLogout} />}>
          <Route index element={<Topics />} />
          <Route path="employeesList" element={<EmployeeList />} />
          <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Route>
      ) : null}
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
// axios.js
import axios from "axios";
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8083/api/v1";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

const refreshAccessToken = async () => {
  try {
    const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
    const response = await axiosInstance.get("/auth/refresh", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${refresh_token}`,
      },
    });
    const access_token = response.data.access_token;
    localStorage.setItem("access_token", access_token);
    return access_token;
  } catch (error) {
    window.location.href = "/login";
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
};

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    if (!config.headers.Authorization) {
      const access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
      if (access_token) {
        if (!config.headers) {
          config.headers = {};
        }
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
      }
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    // 401 Unauthorized
    const originalRequest = error?.config;
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest?.sent) {
      originalRequest.sent = true;
      const new_access_token = await refreshAccessToken();
      originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${new_access_token}`;
      return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

Comment: I think you could dispatch something to the redux store whenever you receive a 401 in your axios instance and then react to the change in redux ( either via a middleware or in a component connected to the redux store )

Comment: I must say i am very new with this, and i have no idea on how to implement what you suggest.
Could you help me out?

Comment: Yep! What part is causing you trouble ? You can do a useSelector inside of your main app component a do a useEffect if you get an authent error from redux to do your redirect

Comment: How will my main app know that an error is happening, in the axios part?
How do i connect the two?

Comment: Normally, you can dispatch to your redux store from axios. Import the store and then do `store.dispatch(myActionCreator())`

Comment: Don't use the hook, use the method dispatch of your store

Comment: I tried something like this, but still got that infinite loop.

catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      store.dispatch(logout());
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252954/discussion-between-axnyff-and-raio).

Comment: Hello.
Checking my loggin state in redux dev tools, store.dispatch worked(i think).
It showed that logged out is false.
Now i only have to deal with the infinite loop and login page redirection.

Comment: You can listen to the redux state inside a component and do a useEffect to handle the redirect. For your infinite loop, you should prevent doing the refresh if you are already logged out

Answer (score -1):

Problem might be without login out user you just redirect to login page. Which might be created infinite loop

```
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(logout());
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  }
```

Comment: It is illegal to use react-redux in a axios file. The following error is showing:
React Hook "useDispatch" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.

But thank you.
Appreciate the help

Comment: Yeah im agree with that that why i only show what is missing what developer problem(Infinte loop). I think if he build event listener and trigger event should work. i hope this explain every thing.